# I can add the function as ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, csv, insert-update

I have a function to insert data to mysql using cvs importer The original code in question is as follows:

```
{
      $sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE '".@mysql_escape_string($this->file_name).
             "' INTO TABLE `".$this->table_name. 
             "` FIELDS TERMINATED BY '".@mysql_escape_string($this->field_separate_char).
             "' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '".@mysql_escape_string($this->field_enclose_char).
             "' ESCAPED BY '".@mysql_escape_string($this->field_escape_char).
             "' ".
             ($this->use_csv_header ? " IGNORE 1 LINES " : "")
             ."(`".implode("`,`", $this->arr_csv_columns)."`)";
      $res = mysql_query($sql);
      $this->error = mysql_error();
    }
```

my question is how I can do that if there is only then update the record to that table without re-inserting new record because I want to insert multiple records and then upload them again but with a field # LL which first will be null and then the update will take values

Comment: 2 things - you should be using `mysql_real_escape_string()`, rather than `mysql_escape_string()`, and it is not recommended to use the `@` error suppression operator.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [MySQL has support for temporary tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html), so one solution would be to insert the CSV data into a temporary table and then JOIN it to the permanent data to identify which rows to update.

Simplified example (assuming your target table is called `datatable`, has a Primary Key called `data_id`, and columns `field_a` and `field_b`):

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_bulk_inserted_datatable LIKE datatable;

LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/data.csv' INTO TABLE temp_bulk_inserted_datatable;

-- Update rows that already exist with new data from the file
UPDATE
    datatable as OLD
JOIN
    -- Inner Join, so that only matching rows will be touched
    temp_bulk_inserted_datatable as NEW
    ON OLD.data_id = NEW.data_id
SET
    OLD.field_a = NEW.field_a,
    OLD.field_b = NEW.field_b;

-- Insert new rows from the CSV file which don't yet exist
INSERT INTO datatable
    ( data_id, field_a, field_b )
SELECT
    NEW.data_id, NEW.field_a, NEW.field_b
FROM
    temp_bulk_inserted_datatable as NEW
LEFT JOIN
    -- Left Outer Join: we want to know about non-matches...
    datatable as OLD
    ON OLD.data_id = NEW.data_id
WHERE
    -- ...in fact, we want ONLY the non-matches
    OLD.data_id IS NULL;

DROP TABLE temp_bulk_inserted_datatable;
```

(Note that I don't actually use MySQL, so some of my syntax may be slightly off, but from what I read in the manual, the above should be correct.)

Comment: Since you asked so nicely(!) I've gone ahead and put an example together for you. Hope that clarifies things. :)